# TYPO3 RTE Stylesheet broken link?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am using this typoscript in my Page TS Config to add a stylesheet to the RTE:

```
RTE.default.ignoreMainStyleOverride = 1
RTE.default.contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte_formats.css
```

I have used this several times perfectly, however I am working on a new server running TYPO3 7.6.11 and the stylesheet does not link.

If I inspect the RTE the css file is linked there, but the link is broken.

I don't know if it is related but in the filelist area if I open the info window for the css file and click the 'Show' button I get a 404 (the same happens for every file, even though they are working fine on the front end).

Comment: Is the file *really* located where it should be? There is nothing wrong with your ts, I have an identical setup and this definitely works.

Comment: @mtness Yes, I have triple checked the the path is correct and the file is intact. If I try typing the direct url to the file in the browser it doesn't work either...?

Comment: The file needs to be accessable by the browser else it will not work.

Comment: @minifranske And how does one make it accessible to the browser?

Comment: Just open it in your browser and make sure it shows :) so open http://your domain/fileadmin/templates/css/rte_formats.css if it doesn't show the path is wrong or some server setting prevents it from being shown.

Comment: @minifranske That's what I'm saying, it doesn't show. Do you know what kind of server issue this would be?

Comment: For instance a setting in a htaccess file. What kind of error do you get when you try to access the file? 404, 403, ...

Comment: @minifranske If I try to access it by the server url like the RTE wants to do it gets 404. I can however access it with no problems with the specific site's domain url.

Comment: What is the difference between the link the rte tries to open and the link that you use to view the css file that works? Maybe you need to add a / in front of the path to the file in the config?

Comment: @minifranske As I said, the RTE uses the server `server.com/typo3/fileadmin...` which doesn't work. But I can the site domain fine `mysite.com/fileadmin...`

Comment: @minifranske As I mentioned in the question, all files appear broken when you go to info > 'show' button in the Filelist.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, file show info also adds the /typo3/ before the fileadmin part but the files are listed in the filelist? What result do you get when you use `RTE.default.contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte_formats.css`

Answer (score 0):

Frontend and Backend need to be completely accessible. A configuration where `server.com` has no access to `fileadmin`and mysite.com with no access to `typo3` is not supported. Both folders hold viable resources for Frontend and Backend.

Comment: So based on the limited info I have, do you think it is most likely a folder permission issue?

Comment: Most likely the one responsible for installing and configuring the server has no experience in TYPO3 and never read any documentation.