# Absolute path to TYPO3 RTE CSS

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

In the Page TSConfig I use the line:

```
RTE.default.contentCSS = fileadmin/template/css/rte.css
```

To link my RTE stylesheet.

Is there any way to use an absolute path to an external file? When I try entering one it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The reason is probably, that everything which is part of the TYPO3 system should be hierarchic located below the root folder. This file is like a configuration file. So why do you want to do that?

Comment: @SvenWappler There is something wrong with this installation of typo3 (or server setting or something I have no control over) that causes the server path to the file to be broken. If I have an absolute path to the file using the site's specific domain it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be possible as [it would allow for XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607894/cross-site-scripting-in-css-stylesheets). As with CSS you can execute JavaScript (thx to IE) this would be a security concern. 
[Subresource Integrity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) is only available for a year and thus is still not implemented in every still used browser.

If your server is broken, fix it. If you can't fix it, abandon the project. If you can't abandon it, you could create an extension holding your viable configuration files, as extensions presumably work.

All in all "half of the installation works" always points to a permissions problem or a typo in the configuration. In the Install Tool there is a check for folder permissions which might help.

Comment: I only work frontend and don't have access to the install Tool. I have an old question about this problem- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303090/typo3-rte-stylesheet-broken-link -if you can shed some light on what might be going on that would be very helpful!

Comment: In both questions you supply to few information to help you and if you don't have access to the system, then you are not the right person to repair it.